# Ionic 3 erro ao compilar para Android: Error: Failed to transpile program

Tags: apache-cordova, ionic2, ionic3, cordova-plugin

Quando dou o comando:

```
ionic cordova build android --debug
```

Dá o erro a seguir, mas no `ionic serve` roda normal... o que estou fazendo de errado?

```
Error: Failed to transpile program
    at new BuildError (C:\wellfitapp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\util\errors.js:16:28)
    at C:\wellfitapp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:159:20
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at transpileWorker (C:\wellfitapp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:107:12)
    at Object.transpile (C:\wellfitapp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:64:12)
    at C:\wellfitapp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\build.js:109:82
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bastou o comando:

```
 Ionic doctor check
```

E fazer as correções.